# Choosing a capacitor capacitance for a quartz resonator (ATMEGA328P)

Tags: capacitance, crystal, atmega328p

I am designing a controller based on an ATMEGA328P-AU chip.

For the chip, I provided an external crystal oscillator at a frequency of 16MHz.

[image]

As a resonator I use [YSX321SL](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/Yangxing-Tech-X322516MOB4SI_C12668.pdf)
[image]

His description refers to load capacitors whose capacitance is equal to 12pF and ESR 60Ω (Max).
I plan to use two load SMD capacitors with a capacity of 22pF each.
The question is, did I choose the right capacity? Or is it worth reducing?

Comment: If the datasheet says you should use 12 pF capacitors, then the device might perform best with, well, 12 pF capacitance; is there any specific reason why you do not want to follow the specifications...

Comment: The ESR value specified is that of the crystal itself and not the load capacitors.

Comment: I have 22pF capacitors, I was thinking about using them. But now I will use 12pF capacitors to achieve reliable operation of the crystal. Thanks for the help!

Comment: May I ask how did the capacitors work out? Because the datasheet says: Load Capacitance: 12pF, 20pF or specify. And if you find out the 16MHz model on LCSC at https://lcsc.com/product-detail/SMD-Crystal-Resonators_Yangxing-Tech-X322516MLB4SI_C13738.html then it clearly says: Load Capacitance: 9pF . So my guess would be that the datasheet is for the whole family of crystals but for this specific one you need 9pF capacitors....

Comment: Load capacitors are phase-shifting for the internal generator of the microcontroller and set its operation mode. The capacitance of the load capacitors depends on the crystal model. Initially, I thought that this is the capacitance of each capacitor connected to the quartz, but this was not the case. Although it worked fine.

Comment: If you suddenly need: Cl = (C1 * C2) / (C1 + C2) + Cstrat.

Cl - capacity of the load capacitors (as indicated in the datasheet)
C1, C2 - capacitance of each of the capacitors
Cstrat is the capacitance of the line and legs of quartz (there is no exact value here, usually they take a number from 1.5 to 5pF).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 12 pF capacitor from each side of the crystal to ground will work just fine.

So like this:

[image]

C1 and C2 need to have a certain value (each capacitor being between 5 pF and 50 pF is normal) to make the oscillator work.

Use the wrong value capacitor and the oscillator circuit will not work reliably.

The only reason to change the values of the capacitors is if you need to make the oscillator work at a **very precise** frequency like 16.000000 MHz.

Then normally a trimmer 1 pf to 22 pF capacitor:

[image]

is used in parallel with the crystal.

But chances are that **you don't need this**.

The microcontroller **doesn't care** about the exact frequency of the crystal oscillator. The frequency you get when using 2 x 12 pF will be more than accurate enough for almost any purpose. Only if you're building a clock you might worry about this.

There is **no need** to use smaller capacitors, you will only increase the chance that the oscillator will stop working!

Also there is no need to worry about the ESR of the capacitors, any modern capacitor should just work.

So: just use two 12 pF capacitors connected like shown above, and stop worrying about this :-)

Comment: Ok, I will use two capacitors with a capacity of 12 pF each. Thanks for the help!